# Class instance of a type synonym

Tags: haskell

The following code

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances  #-}

module Function where

import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import Control.Monad

type Function = V.Vector Double

instance Num Function where
  (+) = liftM2 (+)
  (*) = liftM2 (*)
  negate = fmap negate
```

returns errors like

```
No instance for (Monad V.Vector)
  arising from a use of `liftM2'
```

though it is said in the documentation that `Vector` is an instance of Monad.

Comment: FYI, you may have meant `zipWith (+)` for your instance of `(+)`.  I can't tell what you're actually trying to do, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unboxed `Vector` is not an instance of `Monad`.   Notice the `vector` package exports many different types that are all called `Vector`.  Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector /= Data.Vector.Vector /= Data.Vector.Storable.Vector.